# Layer objects in Flash with their own buttons to pull the object up and lay on top of the prior. How do I setup the Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, button

Here's what I had in mind:

Accessories and build your car application in Flash.

I'm new to the Action Script 3 and I am trying to Action Script my custom graphics for a “build your own car”. Something similar to the Harley Davidson motorcycle builder (https://www.harley-davidson.com/en_US/Content/Pages/H-D1/Bike-Builder.html#/locale__en_US/model_*FLD/year*_2013).

I have all the graphics (multiple photos, photoshopped and cut out for the different car body colors. I'm doing the same with the car rim choices, etc) All the graphics are sized so they will lay on top of one another seamlessly but I don't know how to Action Script 3 the buttons so you can click on (ex: rim1, or rim2 , etc and see how it looks on car by pulling up the photo on top of the existing background car photo) .

How would I Action Scrip my "color button" to come up with 10 color swatches I’ve designed and then when you click on the color swatch (ex: red). It will then put the graphic red of the car body that I have already made on top of the existing background photo of the car and so on for each color button? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

to react to button clicks:

```
//first add listeners to buttons
myButton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
myButton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
...etc

//then do something based on button clicked:
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (event.target)
    {
        case myButton1:
            //do something, eg make a movieclip of a car part visible
            break;
        case myButton2:
            //do something else, eg make a movieclip of a car part invisible
            break;
        ...etc
    }
}
```